# Вывод значения объекта с ключем

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, методы

Есть объект, значения которого я обьединил и отсортировал в порядке возрастания но в конечном итоге мне необходимо получить вывод результата вместе с ключем подобным образом.

Подскажите как мне это реализовать, возможно я изначально неправильно выбрал структуру данных?

// ["210-01-03-03", "210-01-04-02", "211-02-08-11", "210-03-08-11"] и т.д

```
const numberRoute = {

  210: ['10-09-10', '03-08-11', '09-08-05', '01-04-02', '11-03-02', '01-03-03'],
  211: ['20-09-10', '02-08-11', '07-08-05', '15-04-02']
}

const arr = numberRoute['210']
const arr2 = numberRoute['211']

const newArr = Object.keys(numberRoute)

const conc = arr.concat(arr2)
conc.sort()
```

Comment: Язык то программирования хотя бы какой у вас? Добавьте тэг с языком

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, можно попробовать так:

```js
const numberRoute = {
  210: ['10-09-10', '03-08-11', '09-08-05', '01-04-02', '11-03-02', '01-03-03'],
  211: ['20-09-10', '02-08-11', '07-08-05', '15-04-02'],
};

const allRoutes = Object.entries(numberRoute).reduce(
  (acc, [route, dates]) => acc.concat(dates.map(date => [route, date])),
  [],
);

allRoutes.sort(([routeA, dateA], [routeB, dateB]) => dateA.localeCompare(dateB));

const output = `[${
  allRoutes.map(([route, date]) => `"${route}-${date}"`).join(', ')
}]`;

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое простое решение.

```js
const numberRoute = {
  210: ['10-09-10', '03-08-11', '09-08-05', '01-04-02', '11-03-02', '01-03-03'],
  211: ['20-09-10', '02-08-11', '07-08-05', '15-04-02']
}

const result = [];

for(let key in numberRoute){
    result.push(...numberRoute[key].map(date => `${key}-${date}`));
}

console.log(result);
```